# How to test render status: 404 with Rails4 and RSpec when using rescue_from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, http-response-codes

I have a Rails4 application with a 'PagesController'.

The show-method throws a customized Exception 'PageNotFoundError' when a Page is not found.

On top of the controller I defined
`rescue_from PageNotFoundError, with: :render_not_found`

`render not found` is a private method of `PagesController` and looks like:

```
def render_not_found
  flash[:alert]=t(:page_does_not_exists, title: params[:id])
  @pages = Page.all
  render :index, status: :not_found #404
end
```

The rails-log in development-mode shows:

```
Started GET "/pages/readmef" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-02 23:11:35 +0200
Processing by PagesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"readmef"}
  ..
  Completed 404 Not Found in 14ms (Views: 12.0ms)
```

So, it seams my :status => :not_found works, so far.

When I do `curl -v http://0.0.0.0:3000/pages/readmef` curl logs

```
curl -v http://localhost:3000/pages/readmef
* About to connect() to localhost port 3000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /pages/readmef HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8x zlib/1.2.5
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

But the following test with RSpec fails:

```
 it 'renders an error if page not found' do
    visit page_path('not_existing_page_321')
    expect(response.status).to eq(404)
    within( '.alert-error' ) do
      page.should have_content('Page not_existing_page_321 doesn\'t exist')
    end
  end

  1) PagesController renders an error if page not found
     Failure/Error: expect(response.status).to eq(404)

       expected: 404
            got: 200
```

Everything looks fine and even the test.log says 404

```
$ tail -f log/test.log
Started GET "/pages/not_existing_page_321" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-03 09:48:13 +0200
Processing by PagesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"not_existing_page_321"}
  Rendered pages/_page.haml (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.haml (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.haml (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_locales.haml (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.haml (0.6ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 6ms (Views: 4.5ms)
```

I tried different Servers, WebRICK, Thin, unicorn. Everything works as expected in development and production mode. Even the test.log is correct but the test fails.

Can anybody tell me why the test says 200 instead of 404?

Comment: You curled `pages/readme`, not `pages/readmef`. And you havent included your test code.

Comment: _blushing_ @sevenseacat your right I didn't see the missing f in the curl command. And indeed curl works fine and respond with 404. _I really should use my glasses :/ But the spec still doesn't work. I've added it above.

Comment: @sevenseacat Thank's for your comment. It leads me to the real problem . I formulated the question again.

Comment: Similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034644/using-rails-default-exception-translation-in-specs/18034898#18034898

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Although I'm not very happy with this solution, at least this is a work around:

I splited the test into two separate specs. One for testing the response code 404 (with GET instead of visit) and a second to test the alert. The second test is necessary because `get` doesn't render the view - even if `render_views` is defined on top of the spec-file.

```
  it 'response with 404 if page not found' do
    get :show, { controller: 'pages', id: 'not_existing_page_321' }
    expect(response.status).to eq(404)
  end

  it 'renders an error-message if page not found and shows index' do
    visit page_path('page_not_found')
    within '.alert-error' do
      page.should have_content("Page page_not_found doesn't exist")
    end
  end
```

Comment: @Luca Spiller is correct and your solution here is the right one also.

Answer (score 19):

Another approach with RSpec 3+ would be to test for an exception:

```
it 'responds with a 404 if the page is not found' do
  expect { get(:show, id: 'bad_id') }.to raise_error(ActionController::RoutingError)
end
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem here is that you are confusing Capybara feature tests and RSpec controller tests. `visit` is a method provided by Capybara and `get` / `response` are provided by RSpec controller tests - **you can't use them together**.

To test this as a single RSpec controller test you can do:

```
it "returns a not found response" do
  get :show, { id: 'not_existing_page_321' }
  expect(response.status).to eq(404)
  expect(response.text).to match(/Page page_not_found doesn't exist/)
end
```

(N.b. The get line is different from what you posted - I haven't included the `controller` param as if you put this in `spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb` where it belongs you don't need that)

Or as a single Capybara feature test:

```
it "renders a not found response" do
  visit page_path('page_not_found')
  expect(page.status_code).to eq(404)
  within '.alert-error' do
    expect(page).to have_content("Page page_not_found doesn't exist")
  end
end
```