# Using Rails default exception translation in specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2, rspec-rails

My controller is throwing `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` which is what to be expected to be translated into 404.

Now I want to test this behaviour in my controller spec, but it gets exception rather than `response_code` equal to 404. How to make it get this code instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Rails raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` it simply telling you that ActiveRecord was not able to find a resource in your database (usually using `find`).

It is your responsability to catch the exception and to do whatever you want to do (in your case return a 404 not found http error).

A simple implementation to illustrate the above is by doing the following:

`app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found

  private

  def not_found
    render file: 'public/404.html', status: 404, layout: false
  end
end
```

This way every time rails will throw a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` from any controllers that inherit from `ApplicationController`, it will be rescued and render the 404 rails default page located at `public/404.html`

Now, in order to test this:

`spec/controllers/application_controller_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationController do

  describe "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception" do

    controller do
      def index
        raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.new('')
      end
    end

    it "calls not_found private method" do
      expect(controller).to receive(:not_found)
      get :index
    end

  end

end
```

You will need to add the following in your `spec/spec_helper.rb`

```
config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = true
```

Comment: Request specs will also pass through RecordNotFound by default, due to the consider_all_requests_local setting explained here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-middleware