# I want to assert for 404 in spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I want to test my app which redirects to a custom 404, 500 error pages. I turned on *config.consider_all_requests_local = false* in the *test.rb* file to check for the error pages.
Now everything works fine and I am able to fill in the fields and assert with capybara if the path exists in rake routes eg:

```
visit signin_path
```

the problem is if I give a wrong path like

```
visit signin_path + '/xyz' #xyz is incorrent
```

or

```
visit ('/wrongpage')
```

to check for redirection to my custom error page, the test case gives an exception and does not proceed to the expect statement. This is the error:

```
Failure/Error: visit ('/wrongpage')

ActionController::RoutingError:
  No route matches [GET] "/wrongpage"

#then stack trace is printed here
```

I  also tried checking for

```
expect(page).to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
```

when I try to fetch a record with invalid id (like id = 'xyz' instead of integer, which gives a 500 error), same problem is present here, the execution stops and does not proceeds to the expect statement.

I also tried looking on the internet for answers but didn't get what I was looking for, this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25469175/2924562) was close but for

```
visit page_path
```

gives the following error:

```
    Failure/Error: visit page_path('wrongpage')

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `page_path' for ....
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4983354/4172515 I think it would be helpful

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions
```

This was the issue!

It's value should be set as **true**

It can be done in two ways, either set it in test.rb file as:

```
# Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
```

or

```
  before(:all) do
  Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
  end
```

Also, don't forget to check this: *config.consider_all_requests_local = false*, to display your custom error page (in your current environment).

Answer (score 0):

Rails by default expects all routes to be defined in `config/routes.rb`

If you wanted to redirect all unknown routes in to some known endpoint you might add a line like this at the bottom of your routes file:

```
get '*path', to: 'home#index' #or whatever your default root path might be
```

There should be no need to test for 404 error as Rails will raise exception if your route is not found unless you handle it as shown above.